# how does Gmail hide its source

Tags: javascript, html

I just saw something odd, I'm using Google Chrome browser and I right clicked a tab with GMAIL open and selected to view the source. All I had returned was :

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div></div></body></html>
```

How would they have managed to do this  ? I didn't think was possible ??

Comment: I get to see all the page source in Firefox without any issues. Not that it tells me much, because it's obfuscated to the max. Maybe it's a Chrome thing? Chrome and GMail are both from Google after all.

Comment: In my FireFox it is possible to view page source however it is completely unreadable ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because gmail is built with javascript it will also build the page dynamically after it is loaded with javascript.

gmail also uses a lot of iframes, you can have a look at the conent of those by inspecting them with [Firebug for Firefox](http://getfirebug.com)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. Did you use Tools -> View Source in the menu? It shows a lot with me. Maybe you clicked in an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

depends where you click ... (*you clicked in an iframe which is empty, and content is loaded with javascript from other frames...*)

If you go to the **options** -> **tools** -> **view source** you will see the main frame and its code..